# Can't access the class I just created

Tags: c#, oop, class

I hope this is a simple question. I'm building a simple console application in C#.  I have a class:

```
using System;
using Filter;

public class Params
{
    public string key;
    public bool distinct;
    public List<string> fields;
    public string filter;
    public int limit;
    public int skip;
    public bool total;
    public List<Tuple<string, GroupType>> group;
    public List<Tuple<string, OrderType>> order;

    public Params()
    {
        key = "";
        distinct = false;
        fields = new List<string>();
        filter = "";
        group = new List<Tuple<string, GroupType>>();
        limit = 0;
        order = new List<Tuple<string, OrderType>>();
        skip = 0;
        total = false;
    }

    public void AddGroup(string field, GroupType type)
    {
        group.Add(new Tuple<string, GroupType>(field, type));
    }

    public void AddOrder(string field, OrderType type)
    {
        order.Add(new Tuple<string, OrderType>(field, type));
    }
}
```

My program .cs class is:

```
namespace csharpExample
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Params p = new Params();
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use Params in my program.cs class where Main() is called.  I thought I could simply use Params like above. I've also tried to do a using Params; both of these are errors in VS since it can't find the directive. I've also tried adding my own namespace: namespace MyNameSpace; around my Params class. When I do this I still am unable to do a using MyNameSpace; statement as it can't find it.

I just want to extract out a bunch of functions into a class that I can reuse. How do i call this class once it's created?

-Thanks
Thanks for the help.

Comment: "This does not work" is not a good description of the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: When you added it to that namespace, did you try adding `using csharpExample` to your program.cs file?

Comment: Write what error you get when you compile the project.

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Params' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about calling the constructor or the properties you are setting?  You can set the class at the top of your base class and then call the instance of it.  But since it is a static class you should probably use a helper method in the main.

```
namespace Example
{
    public class Program
    {
        Params p = new Params();

        string writefromParams()  // I exist just to give the string back from params with a nonstatic method
        {
            return p.key;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p2 = new Program();  // set up a new instance of this very class

            Console.WriteLine(p2.writefromParams());  // get non static method from class


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still unable to find Params: The type or namespace name 'Params' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have any type of folders or separate projects occurring in your solution?  I literally just removed the namespace portion completely from my params class and got it to work.

Comment: For some reason when I created the new classes in VS 2013 it never added them to the project itself. Instead it just saved them to the same folder and displayed them. It couldn't find the files because of this.

Comment: Glad you got it, keep in mind dealing with static and instance classes are a big part of programming.  Like everyone has listed you will get into issues when mixing the two.  You can do it, it is just not really preferred.  You instead could go back to your other class and set the public strings, constructor, and class as 'static' and have a much easier time of referencing things in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the Params object in the Main function, just add `Params p = new Params ();` to the `Main` function at the top.

Most likely your problem is that Main is static, meaning that it can't access other things that aren't static which are outside of it.  If you declared Params in the Program class, unless you made it static, it can't be accessed in Main.

Comment: Main is static, and Params is in a saperate file.  If it's just the static part then what are my options. I removed static and just called it public void Main(string[] args) and it results in the same error.

Comment: He gets this error: "The type or namespace name 'Params' could not be found (...)", so it's not the problem with static.

Comment: just to be sure, these are in a project right?  You didn't just add Params as an individual file right?